# JavaFX tableview how to edit a cell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm going to code a programm with JavaFX. There I want to change the value of a cell, but I dont know how to do it. I dont want to make a cell editable, but I want to change the value from the side of my code.
[Here is a picture for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZmg1.png)

This is how my code is structured(I dont know if it is relevant). But It is maybe important to know, that the number of columns of the table is variable.

```
public class Turing extends Application {

ArrayList<Character> alph;
String name;
String initState;
String tapeEx;
private final ObservableList<State> states = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new State("state1"));
MainWindowController mainWindowController;
AddStateController addStateController;
EditStateController editStateController;
AddRuleController addRuleController;

//Initial-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Turing.class.getResource("../windows/MainWindow.fxml"));
    AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Turing Machine");

    mainWindowController = loader.getController();
    mainWindowController.setTuring(this);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 900, 600));
    primaryStage.show();

    initTuring();
}

private void initTuring(){
    alph = new ArrayList<Character>();
    alph.add('#');
    name = "name";
    initState = "0";
    tapeEx = "";

    TableColumn statesCol = new TableColumn("state");
    statesCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<State, String>("name"));
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(statesCol);

    TableColumn hashtagCol = new TableColumn("#");
    hashtagCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<State, String>("#"));
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(hashtagCol);

    mainWindowController.getTableRules().setItems(states);
}

//Edit Table--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setAlph(String alphString){
    ArrayList<Character> alphNew = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : alphString.toCharArray()) {
        alphNew.add(c);
    }
    alph = alphNew;
    alph.add('#');
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().clear();
    TableColumn statesCol = new TableColumn("state");
    statesCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<State, String>("name"));
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(statesCol);
    for(int i = 0; i < getAlph().size(); i++){
        TableColumn tc = new TableColumn("" + getAlph().get(i));
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<State, String>("" + getAlph().get(i)));
        mainWindowController.getTableRules().getColumns().addAll(tc);
    }
}

public void addStateBtn(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Turing.class.getResource("../windows/AddStateWindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Turing Machine - add state");

        addStateController = loader.getController();
        addStateController.setTuring(this);
        addStateController.setStage(stage);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 350, 150));
        stage.show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addState(String state){
    states.add(new State(state));
    mainWindowController.getTableRules().setItems(states);
}

public void editStateBtn(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Turing.class.getResource("../windows/EditStateWindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Turing Machine - edit state");

        editStateController = loader.getController();
        editStateController.setTuring(this);
        editStateController.setStage(stage);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 350, 150));
        stage.show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void editState(String state){
    State item = (State) mainWindowController.getTableRules().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if(item != null) {
        item.setName(state);
    }
}

public void addRuleBtn(String actualState){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Turing.class.getResource("../windows/AddRuleWindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Turing Machine - add rule");

        addRuleController = loader.getController();
        addRuleController.setTuring(this);
        addRuleController.setStage(stage);
        addRuleController.setlState(actualState);
        addRuleController.getCbReadSymbol().setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(alph));
        addRuleController.getCbNextState().setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(states));
        addRuleController.getCbWriteSymbol().setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(alph));
        addRuleController.getCbReadSymbol().getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                addRuleController.setReadSymbol(alph.get(newValue.intValue()));
            }
        });
        addRuleController.getCbWriteSymbol().getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                addRuleController.setWriteSymbol(alph.get(newValue.intValue()));
            }
        });
        addRuleController.getCbNextState().getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                addRuleController.setNextState(states.get(newValue.intValue()).getName());
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 350, 375));
        stage.show();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addRule(String actState, char readSymbol, char writeSymbol, String nextState, AddRuleController.tape tapeMove){
    for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
        if (states.get(i).getName().equals(actState)) {
            //mainWindowController.getTableRules().getItems().set(i, new State())
        }
    }
}
```

}

Could somebody help me to solve my problem?
Thank you in advance!

lg bttl

Comment: bruh is nobody able to help me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And don't think "cell" when you want to change "data" ;) You have a list of items with properties you are showing - changes to those properties will show up automagically in the table, provided your setup is correct...